# Finding and comparing a range of characters in one string to another string

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, search

I would like to get the index and value of a string that matches another string.  Example:

```
buff = '01101010'
mystr = '100010101101010000001'
```

I want to search for buff in mystr and if it matches then get the index of the first element that matches and the values.

```
output:
match happens at:
index = 7
value = '01101010'
```

any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `find()` on the string you're trying to match:

```
print(mystr.find(buff)) // prints 7
```

Alternatively you can use a regex:

```
result = re.search(buff, mystr)
print(result.start()) // prints 7
print(result.group()) // prints 01101010
```

Building a function around that to get the expected output should be trivial.